# Have you done single domain with multiple web apps in different paths?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-gateway

So I'm trying to use Application Gateway in Azure and trying to do the following:

Single domain (app.mydomain.com) with path based routing to different web apps

like: http://app.mydomain.com/app1
      http://app.mydomain.com/app2

Any idea how to configure it in Application Gateway?

I'm keep getting 502 Error when I did the routing to my web apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how to configure it in Application Gateway?

If you want to  use path-based routing in the Application Gateway.
Sure, it is possible.

We can use the routing rules to point to a specific backend pool. That backend pool will point to whatever servers you want handling that request.

For more information you could following this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/application-gateway-create-url-route-portal#create-a-path-based-routing-rule). And you also could refer to this [blog](http://devchat.live/en/2018/07/02/how-to-map-url-path-based-rules-in-application-gateway-for-your-azure-web-app-service/) to get more detail steps

Comment: blog link helped Key part is to add the Virtual directory to the Web App and do the HTTPSettings Binding through powershell. Then everything worked!

Comment: I am glad to know that it could help you.

Comment: Trying to accomplish the same but with ssl bindings on app services. Added custom domain to first app service, configured ssl binding, but adding the same cutom domain fails with error that domail already assosiated with another app service.